# Using D3.js to convert map projections on canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, d3.js, d3.geo

What I'm doing:

I have a way to upload an image onto a canvas. Then, I'm using d3's map projections to allow the selection of a different map projection to convert the image to.

The problem:

The conversion only works if the original image is an equirectangular projection. For example, if I upload an equirectangular Earth map, then tell it to convert it to a Robinson projection, it works fine. If I upload a Robinson map image, then try to convert to an equirectangular projection, all it does is fill in the transparent data with color (i.e. it doesn't work).

The code I'm using:

```
function updateMapProjection(selection) {
    var projection = options[selection.selectedIndex].projection;
    //projection var will be something like 'd3.geo.robinson()`
    var projCanvas = document.getElementById('projectionCanvas');
    var projCtx = projCanvas.getContext('2d');
    projCtx.clearRect(0, 0, projCanvas.width, projCanvas.height);
    var tempImage = new Image();
    if (mapFile.indexOf("imgur.com") > -1) {
        tempImage.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
    }
    tempImage.onload = function() {
        projCtx.drawImage(tempImage,0,0, projCanvas.width, projCanvas.height);

        var dx = projCanvas.width;
        var dy = projCanvas.height;

        var sourceData = projCtx.getImageData(0, 0, dx, dy).data;
        var target = projCtx.createImageData(dx, dy);
        var targetData = target.data;

        for (var y = 0, i = -1; y < dy; ++y) {
            for (var x = 0; x < dx; ++x) {
                var p = projection.invert([x, y]);
                if (!p) {
                    targetData[++i] = 0;
                    targetData[++i] = 0;
                    targetData[++i] = 0;
                    targetData[++i] = 0;
                    continue;
                }
                var λ = p[0],
                    φ = p[1];
                if (λ > 180 || λ < -180 || φ > 90 || φ < -90) {
                    i += 4;
                    continue;
                }
                var q = ((90 - φ) / 180 * dy | 0) * dx + ((180 + λ) / 360 * dx | 0) << 2;
                targetData[++i] = sourceData[q];
                targetData[++i] = sourceData[++q];
                targetData[++i] = sourceData[++q];
                targetData[++i] = 255;
            }
        }
        projCtx.clearRect(0, 0, dx, dy);
        projCtx.putImageData(target, 0, 0);
    }
    tempImage.src = mapFile;
    $(".loaderWrapper").hide();
}
```

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vjnfyd8t/3/) for a working example. Notice that instead of actually converting the map, it's just filled in the previously transparent areas with white. The converted image *should* look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBthL.jpg).